# JUnit5 suite ignores tests without "Test" in class name

Tags: java, junit, integration-testing, junit5

I use junit5 and have two classes with integrations tests `FooIT` and `TestBarIT`. This is my configuration

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SelectClasses({ 
        FooIT.class, TestBarIT.class
})
@SuiteDisplayName("Suite IT")
public class SuiteIT { }
```

However, tests in `FooIT` will be ignored if I don't add word `Test` (for example `TestFooIT`). But I don't want to add word `Test` as we have a strict naming convention for tests.

Can anyone say how to make junit suite accept classes without `Test` in their names or to configure it use `IT` for class checking?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a detailed description on how you run your unit tests with all the libraries/framework you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer from JUnit team.

> The @IncludeClassNamePatterns and @ExcludeClassNamePatterns
> annotations are designed explicitly for that purpose.

So,

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@SelectClasses({ 
        FooIT.class, BarIT.class
})
@SuiteDisplayName("Suite IT")
@IncludeClassNamePatterns(".*IT$")
public class SuiteIT { }
```